# What's the difference between Memory 1~4 window of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

Anyone has experience with the Memory window of visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between the 4 memory windows, but having 4 of them is handy in those cases where you want to compare different pieces of memory.

I typically use the memory windows if I have a memory corruption (overwrite) or very strange minidump and I want to look at the underlying data structures.  Since I have written my own memory manager, I can easily (well, almost) see in the memory windows which pieces of memory have been allocated, how big the pieces are, ... and so on.